# Inserting values into a vector at multiple positions

Tags: r, vector, insert

Assume we have a vector like

```
x <- 1:6
```

and I would like to insert the values of the vector

```
y <- 7:10
```

at the positions

```
z <- c(3, 5, 6)
```

of the vector x, i.e. creating the vector

```
c(1,2,3,7,4,5,8,6,9,10)
```

Is there an elegant and flexible way to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function which might help :

```
insert_vector <- function(input, position, values) {
  #Create result vector
  res <- numeric(length(input) + length(values))
  #Create an index of input vector
  inds1 <- seq_along(input)
  #Get the position where we want the input vector in result vector
  inds2 <- inds1 + cumsum(inds1 %in% (position + 1))
  #Insert input vector
  res[inds2] <- input
  #Insert new vector at remaining positions
  res[setdiff(seq_along(res), inds2)] <- values
  res
}

insert_vector(x, z, y)
#[1]  1  2  3  7  4  5  8  6  9 10

insert_vector(c(3, 1, 3, 5), c(1, 3), c(10, 100))
#[1]   3  10   1   3 100   5
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the `insert()`-function from the `R.utils` package (https://rdrr.io/cran/R.utils/man/insert.html).

It does exactly what you asked for but behaves slightly differently.

Note, that with this function, `z` indicates the positions at which `y` should be inserted. In your example, it indicates the indices after which it should be inserted. In other words, you need to shift the indices by +1.

Also note, that your `y` and `z` is of different length. For a non-custom function, this obviously needs to be modified.
Not sure if there is an option with the function to solve this but my solution below should provide flexibility as well.

Given your example, this solves the problem:

```
library('R.utils')

x <- 1:6

y <- 7:10

z <- c(4, 6, 7)


c(insert(x, z, values = y[1:length(z)]), y[-(1:length(z))])
```

Answer (score 1):

An interesting problem. Here is a possible solution:

```
x <- 1:6
y <- 7:10  
z <- c(3, 5, 6)

# complete z so that the lengths of z and y match
z <- c(z, rep(z[length(z)], length(y) - length(z)))
# get index of y values in final results
idx_y <- z + seq_along(z)
# make an empty vector and fill y values at positions idx_y;
# the remaining positions are left for values from x.
m <- rep(0, length(c(x, y)))
m[idx_y] <- y
m[!seq_along(m) %in% idx_y] <- x

identical(m, c(1,2,3,7,4,5,8,6,9,10))
# [1] TRUE
```